# ParseException: Could not parse date - Class: java.text.DateFormat

Tags: java, json, ajax, type-conversion, struts2

My question is not same as that question about get date from JSP.

Now I have a server using Struts 2.2.1

**And the `Action` is like this:**

```
public class AddMeetingAction extends ActionSupport{

private A a;

@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
....
}
//getter and setter..  
}
```

**And the class `A` is like this:**

```
public class A{
    private java.util.Date b;
....
}
```

When I use Postman to make a HTTP `POST` request with parameter `{"b":"2015-01-01"}` to this action, I can get `b` correctly.

or if I write javascript with jQuery `$.ajax()`, `datatype=json`, and get date from bootstrap datetime-picker plugin. It's OK.

but, when *others* call this action using ios, sending the same string, the server throws exception:

```
Could not parse date - Class: java.text.DateFormat
File: DateFormat.java
Method: parse
Line: 357 - java/text/DateFormat.java:357:-1

at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter.doConvertToDate(XWorkBasicConverter.java:377)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter.convertValue(XWorkBasicConverter.java:115)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter.convertValue(XWorkBasicConverter.java:146)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.convertValue(XWorkConverter.java:334)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlTypeConverterWrapper.convertValue(OgnlTypeConverterWrapper.java:39)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getConvertedType(OgnlRuntime.java:1060)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getConvertedTypes(OgnlRuntime.java:1077)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getConvertedMethodAndArgs(OgnlRuntime.java:1103)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1189)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1203)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:1474)
at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setPossibleProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:85)
at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:162)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.ObjectAccessor.setProperty(ObjectAccessor.java:27)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2245)
at ognl.ASTProperty.setValueBody(ASTProperty.java:127)
at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220)
at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:301)
at ognl.ASTChain.setValueBody(ASTChain.java:227)
at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220)
at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:301)
at ognl.Ognl.setValue(Ognl.java:737)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setValue(OgnlUtil.java:209)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.trySetValue(OgnlValueStack.java:173)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:160)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.setValue(OgnlValueStack.java:151)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.setParameters(ParametersInterceptor.java:288)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:199)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:142)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:166)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:485)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)


Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-01-01"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter.doConvertToDate(XWorkBasicConverter.java:367)
... 79 more
```

Comment: post the code where you parsed that date.

Comment: @Aleksandr M  not duplicate.i cannot get date from ios call.jsp ok.thx

Comment: @Saif date parsed by struts2,not my code.the method is convertValue in com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter class

Comment: The date conversion is done based on locale. So it is a dup.

Comment: @AleksandrM you mean the locale of iphone affect struts's date conversion format?

Comment: You need to: 1) change the format sent by iOS, or 2) Create a custom converter. [Reading this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20641525/1654265)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't modify a sender which is requested a locale specific date, then you can at least add a parameter `request_locale` to the request. The rest is done by the [`i18n`](http://struts.apache.org/docs/i18n-interceptor.html) interceptor. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25219888/573032) answer to get more help.

Example:

```xml
<action name="someAction" class="com.examples.SomeAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
    <result name="success">good_result.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Another solution is to change type of the property to avoid conversion errors

```
public class A{
    private java.lang.String b;
....
}
```

If you need to convert it to `Date` you can use `DateFormat`.

Comment: I changed type of property,and convert it using `sdf.parse`method in `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")`class.It works.Thanks for your help.